# Working with git submodules when you're not actively working with git submodules

Tags: git, git-merge, git-submodules

We've recently added a submodule to our git repository. There's one person who's in charge of dealing with the submodule, so most of the developers don't *normally* have to concern themselves with the submodule versions, changes and updates.

It turns out there are certain situations where it becomes impossible to ignore the fact that a submodule is present (as opposed to a regular directory). And unfortunately, most of the documentation on git submodules is focused on how one actively makes changes to the contents of the the submodule, rather than how to effectively *avoid* making active changes to the submodule contents.

The big issue I'm having at the moment is merging. I have my branch, on which I should have no changes to the submodule. I then merge in another branch, which *does* have changes to the submodule. This results in the following in the `git status`:

```
# All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
#   (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
#
...
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   path/to/submodule (new commits)
```

And sure enough, if I do a `git diff`, it shows a change:

```
diff --git a/path/to/submodule b/path/to/submodule
index 0dce5c0..a4df5ed 160000
--- a/path/to/submodule
+++ b/path/to/submodule
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 0dce5c08ea0c1ff9208cc9427aef5872c75f1e1e
+Subproject commit a4df5ed659cf150200a14529e1fc34727213792c
```

Given that there shouldn't be any changes to the submodule on the HEAD branch side of my merge, and that I definitely want my final merged commit to contain the version of the submodule that is on the other branch, how should I resolve this?

On a related note, if I do manage to mess up this merge with respect to the submodule, how would I fix it? That is, what's the "make the submodule match the state it is on a given branch" command? For normal files you can use `git checkout <branchname> -- path/to/file`, but `git checkout <branchname> -- path/to/submodule` doesn't seem to work, despite the header printed by git status indicating that it might.

Comment: Chances are you want `git submodule update`. I've found it useful to stick it in everybody's `post-merge` hook (and make that hook a symlink to a standard location so it can be updated)

Comment: As long as the submodule's own history is sufficiently linear, git should do the right thing for merges in the main repo ... we managed to make this work even with *lots* of people modifying the submodule.

Comment: @o11c If you can explain clearly what `git submodule update` will do (which version will it pick) with a not-yet-commited merge showing the sort of situation which I indicate in my question,  that's an answer I would definitely upvote.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by o11c, even when you're not actively working with submodules, you'll have to perform:

```
git submodule update
```

**When?**

When your developer working with submodule creates new commit in the submodule AND updates your current branch to use these new commits. Then the reference to the submodule has changed and you need to perform `git submodule update` to ask git to propagate these changes to your working copy (file system).

**What does it do?**

`git submodule update` checkouts your submodule at the commit referenced by your current branch in the parent git repository, so that code in the submodule is in sync with code in the parent repository.